# django.db.utils.IntegrityError not solving this part

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, coursera-api

I need a help regarding django.db.utils.IntegrityError:
I read similar questions on Stack Overflow before posting a new question, but I could not find the right solution.

Basically, I am following a course, let's say copy-pasting the code in models.py, serializers.py views.py
And whenever I call python manage.py migrate, I get this error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'LittleLemonAPI_menuitem' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: LittleLemonAPI_menuitem.category_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in LittleLemonAPI_category.id.

Anyone can help, how could I fix that error? The strange part is, that I literally follow each step on the course, it isn't even my code, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

I tried to delete all migration related files and db.sqlite3, but in that way I lose all the previously entered data.

I tried changing the part from `on_delete.PROTECT, default=1`. into `on_delete.CASCADE` and removing `default1,` but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically complaining about not finding a "LittleLemonAPI_category" with id of "1" here:

`'1' that does not have a corresponding value in LittleLemonAPI_category.id.`

You need to insert a category with the id of 1 before inserting your menuitem

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this error,
Comment out the Category class and Foreign Key from MenuItem class like this:
[example with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0GDO.png)

```
from django.db import models

#class Category(models.Model):
#   slug = models.SlugField()
#   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    inventory = models.SmallIntegerField()
    # category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
```

Then remove the 'category' from serializers field. After that, run the server and go to the single menu item from your browser. You can find your single item like that: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/menu-items/2

Delete these items one by one and then remove the class comment, migrate and run again your server. Hope it will work.

Comment: You should use code blocks instead of screenshots, so the other users don't have to open the link, and so they can copy-paste your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will do my best to describe how I got this to work.

> NOTE: I took a backup of my project before getting stuck at the
> `relationship serializers` module. By doing so I was able to export my
> previous data from the database file which I later imported into a new
> database (see step 4 below).

1. **Delete the Database File**: I deleted the `db.sqlite3` file, which is the SQLite database for my Django project. This effectively removes all the data and schema for my project.
2. **Delete Migrations**: I navigated into the `migrations` directory of each Django app in my project and deleted all files there, except for the `__init__.py` file. This removes all migration history for my project.
3. **Flush and Migrate**: I ran the following commands in the terminal:

   - `python manage.py flush`: This command removes all data from the database and resets the database to its initial state. Since I had already deleted the `db.sqlite3` file, this command was more of a safety measure to ensure the database was completely reset.
   - `python manage.py migrate`: This command applies all migrations (which are now only the initial migrations provided by Django for its built-in apps, since I deleted all custom migrations in step 2). This effectively creates a new, empty database for my project.
4. Using the database table/file from before I updated my code (following the instructor) and eventually got stuck at the error described above this post, I exported the `LittleLemonAPI.menuitem` table into `.json` file:

   - `python manage.py dumpdata LittleLemonAPI.menuitem > data.json`

> NOTE: So as to not get confused, the project backup can be named
> whatever you like. What's important is that you have access to the old
> database file and it's situated in the same directory as the manage.py
> file, else the above command won't work.
>
> Again, please make sure this step is done in a different folder from
> your current project directory where you have the new, empty database
> file. Otherwise you won't get any data running the export command.

Below is the content of the `data.json` file:

```
[
    {
        "model": "LittleLemonAPI.menuitem", 
        "pk": 1, 
        "fields": {
            "title": "Chocolate Cake", 
            "price": "2.50", 
            "inventory": 100,
            "category_id": 1
        }
    }, 
    {
        "model": "LittleLemonAPI.menuitem", 
        "pk": 2, 
        "fields": {
            "title": "Vanilla Ice Cream", 
            "price": "1.50", 
            "inventory": 100,
            "category_id": 1
        }
    }, 
    {
        "model": "LittleLemonAPI.menuitem", 
        "pk": 3, 
        "fields": {
            "title": "Strawberry Ice Cream", 
            "price": "1.50", 
            "inventory": 100,
            "category_id": 1
        }
    }
]
```

5. I [downloaded and installed sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-tools-win-x64-3440200.zip) so I could tinker with the database. I pretty much followed the steps in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BomCx0jbwPY). After setting up the environment variables in Windows, I had to restart my VS Code for the changes to reflect in the terminal.
6. Now, after step 3, you basically have an empty database file. I navigated to the directory of my project where the new, empty database file (db.sqlite3) is and ran the following:

   sqlite3 db.sqlite3

This gave me access to the database. So, I ran the following commands to create tables and fill them with data:

- Create a table for `Menu Item`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "LittleLemonAPI_menuitem" (
"id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"title" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
"price" decimal NOT NULL,
"inventory" smallint NOT NULL,
"category_id" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

- Insert Data from the exported `data.json` file:

```
INSERT INTO "LittleLemonAPI_menuitem" ("id", "title", "price", "inventory", "category_id")
VALUES (1, 'Chocolate Cake', 2.50, 100, 1),(2, 'Vanilla Ice Cream', 1.50, 100, 1),(3, 'Strawberry Ice Cream', 1.50, 100, 1);
```

- Create a table for `category`:

```
CREATE TABLE LittleLemonAPI_category (
"id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
"slug" varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
"title" varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I go on to quit out of sqlit3 by running: `.quit`.

7. I configured `admin.py` so I could have access to the admin page:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, MenuItem

admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(MenuItem)
```

Then I go on to create a superuser:

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

This command will prompt you to enter a username, email address, and password for the superuser. The superuser will have full access to the Django admin site.

You should also run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands:

- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate`

Then start the server:

- `python manage.py runserver`

8. Navigate to `http://localhost:8000/admin`, log in with the superuser credentials, and you should be able to see `Categorys` and `Menu Items` in the left panel.

You can select either to view and/or edit the content.

Select `Categorys > ADD CATEGORY` and fill out whatever you like in the `slug` and `title` fields.

You can create as many categories as you like.

Go on to save that.

Then try to access `http://localhost:8000/api/menu-items`

--

Do excuse the formatting - pretty new here.

--

[This](https://github.com/oluatosn-dev/Coursera-DRF-Relationship-Serializers-Week-2) might also be helpful